# How do I get all the interactions I had with a specific Twitter user?

Tags: twitter

When I get a new follower I would like to know if that's because of a recent interaction, either on my side or on their side (mention, retweet, like...). Is there a way to get this ?

Answer (score 0):

A search like this : `user1 user2` or `user1+user2` is enough afaik.

The default operator   is "containing both" i.e.  `+`
Source : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/rules-and-filtering/search-operators

Comment: That would miss "likes" I guess